# entities filtering in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

i have a list of task in my database i want to fetch the tasks by status and priority and the same query should return appropriate result if i do not pass status and priority.i wrote something but this is not good approach
status and priority are varibles of the task  entity
if any ideas please help me am new to spring.thank you in advance

Service:

```
public List<Task> getTasks(String status, String priority, String projectId) {
    if (!status.equals("undefined") && !priority.equals("undefined")
                && !projectId.equals("undefined")) {
            return taskRepository
                    .findByStatusAndPriorityAndProjectIdAndIsDelete(status,
                            priority, projectId, false);

        } else if (!(status.equals("undefined"))
                && (priority.equals("undefined"))
                && !(projectId.equals("undefined"))) {

            return taskRepository.findByStatusAndProjectIdAndIsDelete(status,
                    projectId, false);
        } else if (!(priority.equals("undefined"))
                && (status.equals("undefined"))
                && !(projectId.equals("undefined"))) {

            return taskRepository.findByPriorityAndProjectIdAndIsDelete(
                    priority, projectId, false);
        } else if ((priority.equals("undefined"))
                && (status.equals("undefined"))
                && !(projectId.equals("undefined"))) {
            return taskRepository.findByUsersAndProjectIdAndIsDelete(
                    authUtilService.getLoggedInUser(), projectId, false);
        } else {
            System.out.println("else called");
            return taskRepository.findByUsersAndIsDelete(
                    authUtilService.getLoggedInUser(), false);
        }

    }
```

repository:

```
List<Task> findByUsersAndProjectIdAndIsDelete(User loggedInUser, String id,
            boolean b);

    List<Task> findByUsersAndIsDelete(User loggedInUser, boolean b);

    List<Task> findByTitleIgnoreCaseContainingAndIsDelete(String taskName,
            boolean b);


    List<Task> findByTenant(Tenant loggedInUsersTenant);

    List<Task> findByStatusAndPriorityAndProjectIdAndIsDelete(String status,
            String priority, String projectid, boolean b);



    List<Task> findByPriorityAndProjectIdAndIsDelete(String priority,
            String id, boolean b);

    List<Task> findByStatusAndProjectIdAndIsDelete(String status,
            String projectId, boolean b);
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/gettasks")
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.Summary.class })
    public List<Task> getTasks(@RequestParam("status")String status,@RequestParam("priority")String priority, @RequestParam("projectId") String projectId){

        return taskControllerService.getTasks(status,priority,projectId);

    }
```

task entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
@EntityListeners(TaskEntityListener.class)
public class Task extends AbstractTenantEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "task_id", updatable = false)
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class, ProjectJsonView.class,TaskJsonView.Summary.class })
    long taskId;

    @Column(name = "title")
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class, ProjectJsonView.class,TaskJsonView.Summary.class })
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "status")
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class, ProjectJsonView.class,TaskJsonView.Summary.class })
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "priority")
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class, ProjectJsonView.class,TaskJsonView.Summary.class })
    private String priority;

    @Column(name = "description")
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class, ProjectJsonView.class })
    String description;

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class, ProjectJsonView.class,TaskJsonView.Summary.class })
    Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "complete_date")
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class, ProjectJsonView.class,TaskJsonView.Summary.class })
    Date completeDate;

    @Column(name = "deadline")
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class, ProjectJsonView.class,TaskJsonView.Summary.class })
    Date deadline;

    @Column(name = "isdelete")
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class, ProjectJsonView.class })
    boolean isDelete = false;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class })
    List<Comment> comments;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "tasks_users", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class })
    List<User> users;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class,TaskJsonView.Summary.class })
    Project project;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class })
    List<SubTask> subtasks;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "tasks_tags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "taskid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tagid"))
    @JsonView({ TaskJsonView.class })
    List<Tag> tags;

    public boolean isDelete() {
        return isDelete;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. It really hard to understand what you want because of your question punctuation. Please update with commas and dots.